# How do I play a secure HLS stream on linux?

Tags: linux, streaming, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I have a web service that talks to an audio server (like Pandora/Spotify) to get the HLS track URL for a particular song. To get that URL, I need to provide authentication headers when I call the REST API. I send that URL to my raspberry pi.

How do I play this HLS stream on the raspberry pi, since I assume it requires authentication to access? I looked at gstreamer, livestream.io, etc. and I don't see any options for custom authentication when trying to retrieve and play the live stream. How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `extra-headers` of [souphttpsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-souphttpsrc.html) element.. 
what pipe do you have so far?

I would do something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc extra-headers=... ! decodebin name=d ! audio/x-raw ! autoaudiosink d. ! video/x-raw ! autovideosink
```

However I do not know how to use that extra-headers from gst-launch.. maybe you will have to code it in C (from [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34003#c25)):

```
GstStructure* extraHeaders = gst_structure_new("extra-headers", "Referer", G_TYPE_STRING, "some-uri, NULL);
g_object_set(element, "extra-headers", extraHeaders, NULL);
```